# JAVA & SQL database save changes

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am working on Java GUI application which connects to SQL database on localhost (I use XAMPP). When I change some entry, for example Age, I click on "Save changes", it is saved and changes are done in SQL database, but when I click on ">" or "<" to view next or previous person and then go back to the person, where I did changes, every entry is without changes in its initial state. But when I close the application and reopen it, all the changes which I made are done. This is part of the code where is mistake, I think. Thank you.

```
private void jButtonSaveChangesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
            try {                                                 
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                try {
                    String query1 = "UPDATE list1 SET " +
                            "name ='" + jTextFieldName.getText() + "', " +
                            "surname ='" + jTextFieldSurname.getText() + "', " +
                            "age ='" + jTextFieldAge.getText() + "' " +
                            "WHERE ID = " + jLabelActualID.getText();
                    stmt.executeUpdate(query1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println(e);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
              System.err.println(e);
            }
    }
```

Picture of application:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure to update the state of the updated objects on the IHM too ? It seems stale

Comment: Do you have autocommit switched on OR do you commit your changes?

Comment: If your updates are visible after a restart then you have an issue with refreshing your view with the saved data, not with the update itself. What code is executed when you click < or >?

Comment: Do **NOT** concatenate input values like that into a SQL statements. Please learn how to use a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: "But when I close the application and reopen it, all the changes which I made are done" you are not updating the Collection used in your GUI. You are just updating the DB. Instead of have your component in the "DAO" part, update the POJO than update the POJO in you database.

Comment: Joakim Danielson: My code for viewing previous person is

public void LoadPreviousRecord() {
        try {
            if (!rs.isFirst()) { 
            rs.previous();     
            FillFields();     
            }
          } catch (SQLException e)
           { System.err.println(e); 
            }
    }

Comment: and for FillFields():
public void FillFields() {
         try {
             jLabelActualID.setText(rs.getString("ID"));
             jTextFieldName.setText(rs.getString("name"));
             jTextFieldSurname.setText(rs.getString("surname"));
             jTextFieldAge.setText(rs.getString("age"));

             jTextFieldActual.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getRow()));
 
             jLabelSlash.setText("/ " + rowsCount);
         } catch (SQLException e) {
 System.err.println(e);
         }
    }

rowsCount is assessed in SetResultSet():
rs.last();
rowsCount = rs.getRow();

Comment: @AxelH Sorry, but I am only beginner and I don't know how to do it. Please, can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing, which can be done more safe and automatically with try-with-resources.

This means a commit might not have happened yet. There is an autocommit setting too.

```
        String query1 = "UPDATE list1 SET " +
                        "name = ?, " +
                        "surname = ?, " +
                        "age = ? " +
                        "WHERE ID = ?";
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query1)) { // Closes stmt.
            stmt.setString(1, jTextFieldName.getText());
            stmt.setString(2, jTextFieldSurname.getText());
            stmt.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldAge.getText()));
            stmt.setString(4, jLabelActualID.getText());
            int updateCount = stmt.executeUpdate();
         } catch (SQLException | NumberFormatException e) {
             System.err.println(e);
         }
```

The same may hold (or may not hold) for the SQL connection.

Also one should use a PreparedStatement for security (SQL injection) and type safeness / escaping of backslash, quote in strings. As you see it is even more readable.

Another case is a second application accessing the database: it can use its own cache, thereby be a bit outdated.

Comment: Those are better way to work except that you are still using the UI components in the DAO part instead of a POJO. This is by the way the reason those changes are not visible unless the application is restarted. The GUI is probably using a Collection to fill the fields, those instances are not updated during the "save action".

Comment: @AxelH thanks. It is indeed better style to separate access to the values of GUI fields and updating the database by some values, say fields of a Person class or such. Without a clean design, it could be that erroneously the list of persons is not reloaded after the SQL update.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately when I paste this code I receive error "no suitable method found for createStatement(String)".

Comment: Ok, I was able to run it but unfortunately, it is doing the same thing like before -- I can change any value and it is saved into database. But when I click to next or previous person and go back, the values are in their initial state. I need to reopen application to view any changes.

Comment: 1/2 My code for viewing previous person is: public void LoadPreviousRecord() { try { if (!rs.isFirst()) { rs.previous(); FillFields(); } } catch (SQLException e) { System.err.println(e); } }

Comment: 2/2 and code for FillFields():
public void FillFields() { try { jLabelActualID.setText(rs.getString("ID")); jTextFieldName.setText(rs.getString("name")); jTextFieldSurname.setText(rs.getString("surname")); jTextFieldAge.setText(rs.getString("age")); jTextFieldActual.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getRow())); jLabelSlash.setText("/ " + rowsCount); } catch (SQLException e) { System.err.println(e); } } rowsCount is assessed in SetResultSet(): rs.last(); rowsCount = rs.getRow();